# Могу ли я отображать footer только у одной секции tableView Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Мне нужно, чтобы footer был только у одной секции tableView, а у другой его не было. Возможно ли это?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var footerView = UIView()
    if tasks[section] == [] {
    footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "empty"
    label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 5, width: footerView.frame.size.width, height: footerView.frame.size.height)
    footerView.addSubview(label)
    return footerView
    }
    else {
        return footerView
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if tasks[section] == [] {
        return 0
    }
    return 20
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, один из способов - используйте метод **heightForFooterInSection**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 2 {
        return 0
    }
    return 33
}
```

Comment: Автор спрашивал про footer.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Спасибо, исправил ответ.

Comment: А если я использую custom footer, как мне быть? "let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20))"

Comment: @HewGene Это никак не мешает, если вы вернете высоту 0 в функции heightForFooterInSection, footer не будет отображаться. Если не получается, покажите ваш код.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk как то не выходит. Прикрепил код к изначальному вопросу.

Comment: @HewGene вы в функции viewForFooterInSection возвращаете пустой View если есть данные, а надо наоборот.

Comment: @HewGene И вместо проверки tasks[section] == [] попробуйте tasks[section].count == 0

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk у меня задумка такая, что если есть данные - footer'a не должно быть вовсе

Comment: @HewGene Понял. Вы можете выложить демо-проект на GitHub? Данных, которые есть недостаточно чтобы увидеть проблему.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk https://github.com/EVGKZN/demoproject/invitations

Comment: @HewGene footer-а не должно быть, если строки в этой секции существуют, я правильно понял? Или какое-то другое условие?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk я использую footer как показатель того, что в секции нет ни одной ячейки, чтоб примерно по середине серым текстом было "empty". Если же в секции есть хотя бы одна ячейка, footer'a быть не должно вовсе.

Comment: @HewGene отправил исправление на Github. Дело в одном условии: в heightForFooterInSection у вас вместо  if tasks[section] == [] должно быть if tasks[section] != []

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk действительно. Да простит меня stackoverflow, но спасибо вам большое за помощь и потраченное время

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, к примеру.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section != 0 {
        // скрыть
        return 0.0
    } else {
        // показать
        return HEIGHT_YOU_WANT
    }
}
```

Официальная документация
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate

Comment: А если я использую custom footer, как мне быть? "let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20))"